# Additive, covariant functor commutes direct limits, then it commutes with direct sums?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Suppose $T:R-Mod \to R-Mod$ is an additive covariant functor that preserves direct limits. (R is commutative, unital. Noetherian if it suits you even).  That is, if $(W_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ is a direct system of R- modules over a directed set $\Lambda$, then the canonical map

$\varinjlim T(W_{\alpha}) \to T( \varinjlim W_{\alpha}) $ is an isomorphism.

Then why is it true that T also preserves direct sums? By this I mean that if $(M_{\theta})_{\theta \in \Omega} $ is a family of R-modules, then the canonical map

$r : \oplus T(M_{\theta}) \to T(\oplus M_{\theta}) $ is an isomorphism.

My problem: How am I supposed to connect coproducts and direct limits? I know that they're both colimits, but I don't know if a direct sum can be viewed as a direct limit of  a system of modules? Since T is additive, it preserves finite direct sums, but that's about all I've got.

Comment: For your directed system take sums over finite subsets of your indexing set. Since the sum of finite sums is finite, it is directed. The colimit will be $\bigoplus M_\theta$ since elements have finite support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finite direct sums are preserved since we deal with additive functors.

Now use the fact that direct sums are directed colimits of finite direct sums. Explicitly, we have

$$\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i = \operatorname{colim}_{E \subseteq I \text{ finite}}\, \bigoplus_{i \in E} M_i.$$